# Why can't I see android.support.v7 files?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to do the demo for the new Cast SDK (for using Chromecast), but I'm having trouble. I downloaded a demo for Android, and I'm getting errors in my project when trying to import anything from `android.support.v7` library.

If I try to import from android.support.v4 or android.support.v13, things show up, but nothing shows up when I try to import from android.support.v7. It seems as if I don't have these files, but when I open the Android SDK Manager, it seems that I have most things installed (Android 3.0 API 11 and above).

Does anyone know why I might be missing this, or how to get it up and running?

Here are the files that I need to import for my demo:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider;
import android.support.v7.media.MediaRouteSelector;
import android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter;
import android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter.RouteInfo;
```

Comment: You can go to project properties,--> Java build path-->Add External Jar-->get your support library from adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat or grid layout or  media router\libs.

Answer (score 4):

If you wants to integrate actionbar below android sdk 3.x use given link reference: 
Android Demo:
http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html

"uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="7"

Support Library classes that provide support for android sdk 2.x and above.

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("ActionBar Support Demo");
}
```

}

http://www.coderzheaven.com/tag/android-support-v7-appcompat-jar/

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple v7 libraries: appcompat, mediarouter and gridlayout. Follow the steps [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) to import and set them up (use Android Libraries with Resources); you need to install appcompat first and then mediarouter and make sure the mediarouter library lists appcompat as part of its dependency.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already downloaded libraries, it will be present in android-sdk 
at following location.

**android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\mediarouter\libs\android-support-v7-mediarouter.jar**

similarly include other jars as well from follwing folder.

**android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7**

add these jars in your android project inside libs folder.

Comment: Since these libraries provide resources, including them as simple jars is not the right solution; they need to be imported as libraries.

Comment: Yes, they can be added as libraries as well. Just to provide faster way to work out Demo Project.

Comment: There is a very good chance that they won't work properly since resources would be missing, that is the reason they need to be imported as libraries and not as jars, otherwise one wouldn't bother with that. It is not a matter of speed of development, it simply won't work.

Comment: How do you import them as libraries in Android Studio?

Comment: From the Google Cast Download page...
`Developing with the Google Cast Android APIs requires Google Play services 4.2, which began rolling out to devices worldwide on February 3rd. Once the update to devices is complete, the corresponding Google Play services library (revision 15) will be available for download from the Android SDK Manager.`

I believe I have everything else needed installed, but my Google Play Services on my Android SDK Manager say it is revision 14, not 15. I don't have the ability to update it either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the import of MediaRouter by adding this line into the dependencies inside the build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:21.0.3'
```

Android Studio imports that as a library so there won't be any troubles with the resources at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and install Android Support Repository using the SDK Manager in Android Studio.
After that add the dependencies inside the build.gradle file as shown below

```
dependencies {    
'compile com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.0.0'
}
```